# Calculating the capacitance for a voltage multiplier circuit

Tags: capacitor, rectifier, multiplier, time-constant

Recently, I've been asked to create a voltage multiplier, with an output voltage \$Vo = 5*Vi\$, where \$Vi\$ is the peak input voltage. This was accomplished without much issues through the schematic below (keep in mind that the capacitors are electrolytic):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzjq9y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Theoretically, it does exactly what I want, presenting a \$5Vi\$ voltage between the terminals illustrated. However, one second requirement for this circuit is to use a filter capacitor in order to keep the output constant; this capacitor **must have the lowest possible value considering the load in the circuit's output as a 100kOhm resistor**.

Normally, I would calculate a filter capacitor so that the input signal's period is lower than the time constant between the capacitor and its load:

\$ T < R*C\$

Considering an input source with signal \$Vi(t)=10sin(4000πt)V\$, we would have a period of 0.0005 seconds; therefore:

\$ 5*10^{-9} < C\$

Yet, since the resistor will be placed in parallel between the terminals denoted by the \$5Vi\$ in the image above, I don't think a filter capacitor is needed. Instead, the capacitors from 1 to 5 are already capable of keeping a pretty stable signal with most values (according to my tests) when using a 100kOhm load.

However, I should use the minimum possible value for the filter capacitor, which in my case (I presume) would be a value related to all capacitors. **How can I, in my circuit, calculate the minimum possible value for the capacitors, keeping a time constant that is superior to the source's period?**

For this particular circuit, since it's not specified in the task document, I would say that the tolerable ripple would be of around 7.5V. The output voltage, errors considered, could be of \$5Vi\pm10\%\$.

Comment: You left out important specifications: **How much ripple is tolerable?** and **How close to 5*V must be the output?** You could use 6 diodes and 6 *very* small caps, and get only 5*V out at high ripple. But even 100 Fd caps would still not produce *zero* ripple and *exactly* 5*V once loaded.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for pointing it out! To be honest, these weren't specified either: all I was given was the input and what the output should be. I added said specifications to the question, trying to keep them at reasonable values. If anything else needs clarification, let me know!

Comment: See https://www.hindawi.com/journals/jece/2017/4805268/